# The correct way to title a work of art

Tags: word-usage, titles

Should a work of art have an author first, and then the title, or the title first, and then the author?

Answer: (...less than 10 rep ATM..)

A work of art may have the author first, and then the title. Or, it may have the title first, and then the author. Both are correct usages of English.

(P.S. I asked this before.. apparently it was deleted. So, I am re-asking and re-answering to make both the question and answer more specific..)

Comment: To whom or for whom are you writing? And what -- a bibliography? There is no ISO standard, after all; every publisher has their own ideas.

Comment: Not a bibliography actually. A caption, in fact.

Comment: Then your publisher should tell you; or, if you're not being paid, you can use whatever caption you think is most useful and appropriate, consistent with all the other captions and conventions in its context. Writing is just technology, and whoever prints the book is in charge; think of editing as customizing a sports car for racing, or arranging a minuet for the tuba, if you like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are writing a label, traditionally museums followed: title of piece, medium, artist's name, birth and death date,  time of [floruit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floruit) (if appropriate to the exhibition), and donor information but [it was always varied](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Museum_label)

The current style found in this Tate Modern is [artist name and birth/death on same line, short bio, tile of work, medium, provenance](http://www.claireantrobus.com/wp/wp-content/uploads/2011/01/IMG_1146.JPG)